# OpenVPN server fails to start when using auth-user-pass-verify

Tags: openvpn

This is my OpenVPN server configuration (it works perfectly)

```
local mydomain.com
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN subdomain.mydomain.com"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.157.149"
push "block-outside-dns"
push "route 192.168.157.149 255.255.255.0"
push "route 0.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway"
push "route 64.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway"
push "route 128.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway"
push "route 192.0.0.0 192.0.0.0 net_gateway"
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.1.0.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

I wanted to enable use of same client with different usernames. So I edited the config and added the below lines in the server.conf file

```
script-security 2 # must be at least 2
auth-user-pass-verify /home/forge/scripts/checkUser.sh via-file
username-as-common-name # without this openvpn will use cn in the certificate as username
duplicate-cn # you may need this if everyone is using same certificate
```

With this (above) additions in the config, openvpn server refuses to start.

To debug, I commented the above lines and uncommented one by one. So now I can pin point that the line `auth-user-pass-verify /home/forge/scripts/checkUser.sh via-file` is causing the issue.

There was no clue on why it is failing in the `systemctl status` or `journalctl -xe`. The file `checkUser.sh` is fully executable by any user in the system. The log file `status-server.log` is also empty.

Though `sudo systemctl start openvpn-server` fails, running openvpn directly works: `sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`!!!

This is how `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service` looks:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN service for %I
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=man:openvpn(8)
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
Documentation=https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
WorkingDirectory=/etc/openvpn/server
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status %t/openvpn-server/status-%i.log --status-version 2 --suppress-timestamps --config %i.conf
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_IPC_LOCK CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE CAP_NET_RAW CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_CHROOT CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
LimitNPROC=10
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
DeviceAllow=/dev/net/tun rw
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true
KillMode=process
RestartSec=5s
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Could someone please point out what could be the issue?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to use 1 device with 1 certificate but authentication through username and passwort for multiple users on this device, correct? And what's the error when starting? And what's in your `/home/forge/scripts/checkUser.sh` file?

Comment: @Lenniey No. I want to use multiple devices with 1 certificate. E.g 10 users will all use the same ovpn file/certificate. I'll identify them using their username. ```checkUser``` verifies the user account in the db. There is no error specifically when starting. It just says 

```Job for openvpn-server@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.```